# Reflecting my payload in source code of the page

Tags: xss

When I am testing an application I tried do some XSS attacks on the application,when tried to execute this payload `%3e%3cb%20onbeforescriptexecute=prompt(document.domain)%3e` its going to the source code of the page, but I am not getting any output in the application.

Can anyone help me to how to get an pop-up in the application?

Comment: What payloads are valid and what payloads won't do anything depends on the application and where exactly it puts the payload. We can not help you without any information about the application you are targeting.

Comment: Did you check the console? Maybe it was stopped by the Chrome or IE XSS Auditor?

Answer (score 1):

onbeforescriptexecute isn't a valid event listener attribute as far as I'm aware. Try using a different payload like `><body/onload=alert(document.domain)>`

You can find a list of the different events you might be able to use here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Event_Handlers

Also, make sure that the reflection appears unencoded.

Comment: It's not standard, but it does exist: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onbeforescriptexecute